# How can The Accursed One deflect Thor's Hammer?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world, mjolnir

When Thor was calling for his hammer and ready to strike the back of the Accursed One, it deflected the hammer with a back fist. From reading stack posts regarding hammer, it should have not happen. "Thor's Hammer enchantment cannot be lifted, moved by anyone except Thor or Someone worthy".

Comment: Deflecting Mjolnir has been the stock in trade for Thor villains since the dawn of time. Most learn they can deflect it but cannot catch or grab it. Known deflectors include the Destroyer, the Absorbing Man, the Molecule Man, the Wrecking Crew, Magneto, The Hulk, and other assorted cosmic level beings such as Galactus or Odin.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mjolnir's "cannot be lifted" property (which does not include "cannot be moved") only applies when it is dropped or set aside. (*Thor* volume 1) Adamantium has also proven to be impervious to a strike from Mjolnir, proving that it *can* be blocked, as well as trading blows with other weapons made from uru, the metal from which Mjolnir is crafted.

Mjolnir has also been damaged on several occasions, from being sliced in twain to being completely vaporized (by interrupting the bonds between its atoms).

Finally, enchantments on Mjolnir *have* been removed in the past. Specifically, it used to be able to be used for time travel, but that enchantment was removed by Immortus (with Thor's permission).

For the specific encounter you're referring to, I'll note again that Mjolnir's property "cannot be lifted" does not prevent it from being moved or deflected, and is only active when set down (or dropped), not swung or thrown.

Comment: There's one scene in AoU that kind of contradicts this(not entirely though)... QuickSilver grabbing Thor's hammer mid-flight... & Crashing .... How does that fit into this??

Comment: @Stark07 cannot "grab", but can be moved/deflected.

Answer (score 1):

I was just watching the movie and I just thought of a way it could be easily deflected. Think of how the "Accursed" get there power. From the Aether. And what is the Aether? An infinity stone but more importantly the reality stone, which can alter the reality of things around the user. So it could be presumed the power given from the aether altered the effects of the hammer on him. Either that or you can just say it's power from an infinity stone which predates his hammer by a long shot and no matter how powerful the hammer is the stones are more powerful. Well at least in the scope of how hard he threw his hammer at the accursed which I think is far from the full strength the hammer could give.

Comment: Can you provide any sources for you answer, to support it and make it stronger. Also take a look at our [tour] to learn more about the site and earn your first badge!

Answer (score 0):

Above is true for the comics. But we're talking about the Cinematic Universe here. And in *Thor: Ragnarok* when Thor returns to Asgard and Loki is disguised as Odin. Thor states:

> "you know that nothing will stop Mjolnir as it returns to my hand. Not even your face."

In my opinion, for the Cinematic Universe, it should not have been possible.